# I can't get the background image

Tags: python, html, django, frontend, backend

Here are some files from project.

my setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for advice_lancing project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(71f#n^0en3u1=j=%bthg1m%d2=so=3+@p6=2u+5k)04caf+od'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'markdownx',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'advice_lancing.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'advice_lancing.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
    'vendor/bootstrap/css/',
    'static/css',
    'static/img',

]
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/pics/'
```

main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from markdownx import urls as markdownx
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^markdownx/', include(markdownx))
]
```

main HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'img/favicon.png' %} ">
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Advice Lancing</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'allblogs' %}">
                Advice lancing</a>


            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'allblogs' %}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">My Blogs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Header -->

    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: {% static 'img/home.jpg' %}">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Advice Lancing</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">Here You Write your Subheading</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                {% for blog in  blogs.all %}
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="{% url 'detail' blog.id %}">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            {{ blog.title }}
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            {{ blog.subtitle}}
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">{{ blog.publish_date_pretty }}</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                  <img src = "{{ blog.image.url }}" height=200 width=200/>
                <br />
                  <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
             {% endfor %}

                <hr>
                <!-- Pager -->
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="next">
                        <a href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Advice lancing 2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jqBootstrapValidation.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/contact_me.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/clean-blog.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allblogs , name='allblogs'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
    path('about/', views.about, name ="about"),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here are my directories Tree :[Directories Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYQi3.png)

I am not getting any error but it is not showing the background image. actually it's not loading because on clicking that area I didn't get any open image option.

**located on the main HTML template line is:**

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: {% static 'img/home.jpg' %}">
```

Comment: Can you output some network/console errors you're seeing?

Comment: I am not getting any error that the main problem it just show no image on webpage just a white space

Comment: In your browser, can you navigate to the image itself and will it load or does it give you a 404?

Comment: no, I think it's not loaded because I am not getting any like open image at new tab and also inspecting no image element is there

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

just change the code from this

`<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: {% static 'img/home.jpg' %}">`

**to this**

`<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('static/img/home.jpg')">`